# Code calling a method which is ambiguous with itself?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a line of code like this:

```
var results = new GroupedCountsModel { XAxis = entities.ListGroupKeys(fieldNameX) };
```

When I try to compile this code, I get a build error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'MyProject.Shared.QueryGeneration.GroupByHelper.ListGroupKeys<TEntity>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity>, string)' 
and 
'MyProject.Shared.QueryGeneration.GroupByHelper.ListGroupKeys<TEntity>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity>, string)'    
C:\{mypath}\MyProject.Shared\Controllers\BaseEntityController.cs
```

This is interesting because the two methods listed in the error are exactly the same. It's not like I have the same method signature defined in a different namespace or assembly. I don't know why the compiler thinks they're different when the compiler itself is pointing to the same method twice. Here is that method:

```
public static class GroupByHelper
{
    public static List<object> ListGroupKeys<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string fieldName)
        where TEntity : class, IDataEntity
    {
        //...etc...
    }
    //...etc..
}
```

What could be causing this? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: try restarting visual studio.

Comment: If that's an ASP.NET project, then try clearing the Temporary ASP.NET Files, and rebuilding the entire solution. There may be two different versions of the temporary assemblies, causing two different classes with the same exact name and namespace.

Comment: yea, I was thinking it was a cache or temp file problem.

Comment: It might be a good idea to clean your solution first, maybe something went wrong there. `Build` -> `Clean solution`

Comment: Yes, good advice. I have done this. Cleaned each individual project and cleaned on the solution level.

Comment: I've also seen this happen when you have different version-numbered assemblies, which may not be your case but worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was odd. I'm not sure how this happened.

I had been refactoring a solution. Some namespaces and classes that were in the startup project had been reevaluated and the decision was made to move them into a MyProject.Shared class library. Somehow, during the refactoring, the MyProject.Shared project ended up referencing itself. I don't recall adding this reference myself, though anything is possible at this point :-) I did use some third party tools designed to seamlessly move namespaces and classes around a solution, so perhaps that's where the reference came from. Or I may have been confused in the solution explorer and added the reference to itself instead of to the startup project. idk.

Once I removed the reference to MyProject.Shared from MyProject.Shared, then the solution compiled normally.

Thanks to those who suggested that I check referenced assemblies and their versions. That's what caused me to notice the self reference.